# Decrypt cipher texts encypted with the same one time pad key

Tags: encryption, cryptography, one-time-pad

I have two pieces of ciphertext encrypted with a stream cipher using the same key.

How do I recover the plaintext of both ciphertext messages without knowing the key used?

Comment: Start over: Do you [A] have two messages THAT ARE encrypted - and thus, two cipher texts? Or do you [B] have two messages AND two cipher texts? In cast it's [B], why are the two messages relevant?

Comment: @medivh, obviously, I have two messages THAT ARE encrypted with only one one time time pad key. And I want decode these two -- get plain texts from them.

Comment: And if I understand correctly, you have the encryption key, too? EDIT: That is to say, the "one stream cipher key" you mention is the one time pad that was used?

Comment: @medivh look at my update.

Comment: See [How does one attack a two-time pad (i.e. one time pad with key reuse)? on crypto.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2249/how-does-one-attack-a-two-time-pad-i-e-one-time-pad-with-key-reuse) and [Taking advantage of one-time pad key reuse?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/59/taking-advantage-of-one-time-pad-key-reuse)

Comment: Stream ciphers and one-time-pads are mutually exclusive. One time pads are not used in real-life anymore, so it is highly unlikely that one is used here.

Comment: "One Time Pads are not used in real life any more" eh, the messages might have been encrypted in WW2, we don't know yet. Also: I don't think you're right actually. I can't believe that we've *entirely* abandoned the only truly unbreakable encryption.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the two encrypted messages are using the same stream cipher and the same key,

`C1 xor C2` results in `M1 xor M2` where C1 and C2 are the respective ciphertext and M1 and M2 are the corresponding plaintext.

You can then recover the plaintext using a technique known as crib dragging. You take a common word or phrase that may appear in the plaintext (such as " the ") and xor that against the result of `M1 xor M2`. If one of the plaintexts had the text of the crib (" the " in our example), then the result of the xor is what the other plaintext had in that position. If neither plaintext contains the text of the crib, it is very likely that the result of the xor is just gibberish.

You just continue this technique until you recover enough of the plaintext to intelligently fill out the rest.

Comment: He HAS the Onetime Pad - he doesn't even have to mess with XOR. That's why I asked so many questions of the (Initially unclear) first post. EDIT: Never mind, he doesn't have the OTP. Disregard this comment while I go cry in my cave.

Comment: does it work if the messages have different lengths?

Comment: @MariusKavansky You can only recover as much of the key as the length of the shorter message.

Comment: What if we have no knowledge of what any of the plaintexts had?

Answer (score 4):

This is known as *OTP key reuse attack*; you can find the answer ("cribtext drag") in [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2249/how-does-one-attack-a-two-time-pad-i-e-one-time-pad-with-key-reuse). The more messages you have (the more the key has been reused), the better. With a large enough corpus you may not even need cribtext dragging at all.

> That is, you take a guess of a common phrase that may appear in one of
>   the plaintexts (the classical example against ASCII english is the 5
>   letter " the "), and exclusive-or that against the XOR of the two
>   original messages in various locations. If one of the plaintexts had
>   the text of the crib (" the " in our example), then the result of the
>   exclusive-or is what the other plaintext had in that position; if
>   neither plaintext had that, it's likely that the result of the
>   exclusive-or is just gibberish. And, once you have a plausible short
>   section, you can extend it (for example, if you know that one of the
>   plaintexts is " na**", you can go through the dictionary of all words
>   that start with "na", use those as cribs, and see which makes the
>   other plaintext make sense).

Of course, you can only use the *shortest common length* of several messages: if you have one 1500 bytes, one 1000, and one 500, you have a three-reuse for the first 500 bytes, a two-key for the next 500, and the last 500 can't be attacked.

Unless the OTP is *also* reused "in time", i.e. periodically (it's no longer a OTP, but then one might argue that it wasn't in the first place, since it is being reused...). This kind of error was done on a brand of encrypted hard disks, every one of which had a different OTP key *[that was then used for every single sector](http://www.h-online.com/security/features/Enclosed-but-not-encrypted-746199.html)* (including zeroed ones - an extreme form of crib), leading to an effective encryption strength of nil. Then, if the original OTP sequence is all included in messages for which you have duplication, you can recover the key from *those*, and then happily go on decrypting *everything else*.